# How do I create a pop up window using tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

My program is a stock management system. So, when it is a specific month I want a pop-up window to be shown to the user indicating that a specific percentage discount should be applied to the product.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing yet as I am only a beginner and I'm not sure of what you can use. I was hoping for some help and guidance

Comment: You should read through some documentation and search for answers online before asking here. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to import `datetime` and find out what month it is. Then check the current month to see if you want to display a message for that month.

Tkinter comes with several options for pop up messages. I think for your specific question you want the `showinfo()` method.

Here is a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime


this_month = datetime.now().month

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text="This is the main window").pack()

# this will display pop up message on the start of the program if the month is currently April.
if this_month == 4:
    messagebox.showinfo("Message", "Some message you want the users to see")   

root.mainloop()
```

Update:

In an attempt to help both the OP and the other person answer the question I have reformatted their answer to something more functional.

@George Sanger: Keep in mind that the `mainloop()` should only be called on the instance of `Tk()` that all tkinter applications are build off of. The use of `Toplevel` is so that you can create new windows after you have already created a main window with `Tk()`.

```
import tkinter as tk


percentage = 0.3

#tkinter applications are made with exactly 1 instance of Tk() and one mainloop()
root = tk.Tk()

def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Toplevel(root)
    popup.wm_title("!")
    popup.tkraise(root) # This just tells the message to be on top of the root window.
    tk.Label(popup, text=msg).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy).pack()
    # Notice that you do not use mainloop() here on the Toplevel() window

# This label is just to fill the root window with something.
tk.Label(root, text="\nthis is the main window for your program\n").pack()

# Use format() instead of + here. This is the correct way to format strings.
popupmsg('You have a discount of {}%'.format(percentage*100))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

Quick Google, edit from code on
https://pythonprogramming.net/tkinter-popup-message-window/

```
import tkinter as tk

percentage = 0.3

def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Toplevel()
    popup.title("!")
    label = tk.Label(popup, text=msg) #Can add a font arg here
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()

popupmsg('You have a discount of ' + str(percentage*100) + '%')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But unfortunately, it is not working even when I changed the font to ('arial',40,'bold')

Comment: Yeah had some paying around, you don't need an argument there, so you can just clear it as in my up-dated code.

Comment: Do not use `tk()` for pop up windows. There are already several built in methods for pop up information and for any standard application if you need/want to do something customer you should use `Toplevel()` instead of `tk()` as `tk()` is most likely being used for the main GUI.

Comment: @user9441606 The reason George Sanger's example is not working is probably due to the missing import information. If you do not import tkinter his code will not work for you.

Comment: @GeorgeSanger Your program has a few issue. 1st you need to show what imports are needed for this code. 2nd you are sending three arguments to a function that can only take one. I think you need to change `popupmsg('You have a discount of', str(percentage*100), '%')` to this: `popupmsg('You have a discount of {}%'.format(percentage*100))`. 3rd your example uses `Tk()` however the main program will be using `Tk()` so you should be using `Toplevel()` here instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Mike-SMT. I'm a beginner who still has lots to learn :)

Comment: @user9441606 try my newest code, and are you running another tkinter window? or is this pop up the only window from your code.

Comment: @GeorgeSanger you are going to run into issues with your new code as well. You have not corrected the formatting issue with your argument for `popupmsg` and you are running mainloop on `Toplevel()` instead of a root `Tk()` instance. Please make sure your code runes without error before posting an answer.

Comment: @GeorgeSanger I have added some details to my answer so you can see what all is needed for your code/answer to be a better answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I am very greatful. And to answer your question... I have another window open that is a stock management system so when It is a specific month I want another window to open saying they should issue a discount on the product

Comment: @GeorgeSanger is it a problem if i am running another tkinter window?

Comment: no it was just with my first code I had was assuming that you were had didn't. but it means it would be better to run a Toplevel() from your main windows.
'
popup = tk.Toplevel(root)
'
where root is your main window object. if I'm explaining it right